# How to read a SQLite database from external storage with Lollipop

Tags: android, sqlite, android-5.0-lollipop

My App is based on a lot of data stored in a big sqlite file. (500MB). This Database is downloaded from a server at first start and will never change again. (Only read Access). Everything is already working, but the data is stored on the internal sdcard since KITKAT. Now with Lollipop we have new features storing the data to the external SD-Card. With this new feature I have problems.

Use Case
- User starts the app the very first time

- User will be asked in which folder the data should be stored with the new introduced ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE
- The App downloads the database and stores it to the folder
- The App shows the data.
- User quits the app
- User starts the app again.

Now. How can I detect which folder the User has choosen at first start ? I don't like to show the Tree Dialog again. (Do I have to store any Path in preferences myself ?)

and

How do I access the downloaded Database in that folder ?

```
myconnection = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(<MyPath>, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY); // <MyPath> is like /sdcard/selectedfolder/mydatabase.sqlite
```

Comment: Have you tried this? https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html#permissions

Comment: Thanks for helping, but I guess this is only to save the permissions. I need to know/or understand, how I get to the path in a second start, which the User selected before in the first start. appdatapath=getTheSelectedFolder();

Comment: Oh, ok, fortunately that is the easy part - save it in Shared Preferences or something like that.

Comment: Right, whats the problem with saving the path in SP and retrieving it after that?
You'll get the Uri in your onActivityResult()

Comment: Ok Sounds good when it is easy :-). Ok I get the URI from SP and now can someone give me the codesample at start of the app and replace the <???> in my following code please ( SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(<???>, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

Comment: See the SharedPreferences docs at http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html

Comment: @Chris : No training needed :-) I know howto use and assume I will fetch the URI from the SP. But howto to read the SQLLiteDatabase which is the main question. If you know what to fill in <???> in the comment before, the question is answered.

Comment: The answer is at that link - obtain your path, write it to shared preferences in accordance with the link, then on the next run read it back again and pass it to the database API.

Comment: Is the following that what you want to tell me regarding the <???> ? : SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(   obtainedURI_from_SP.getPath() + "mydb.sqlite" , null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY) // obtainedURI_from_SP.getPath()  has the value "/tree/primary/selectedfolder"

Comment: Did you find the answer? I have the same problem, passing `uri.getpath` to `openDatabase` method doesn't work and throws error.